# Excel Autofill between worksheets with cell reference

Tags: excel-2013, autofill

In sheet1 I paste in information from another source that has a regular pattern of data but does not paste as a single row. Instead it takes up three rows and repeats. See example diagram below.

```
 /       A       B            C        D      
 1    38518  2/2/2016    2/16/2016   
 2           John Doe                MDUDM
 3           Comment1                Location1
 4    38519  2/3/2016    2/18/2016
 5           Jane See                CADME
 6           Comment2                Location2
```

In sheet2 I can write formulas to collapse the information I need into a single row.

```
 /       A             B          C             D             E
 1   =Sheet1!A1   =Sheet1!B1   =Sheet1!B2   =Sheet1!B3   =Sheet1!D2
 2   =Sheet1!A4   =Sheet1!B4   =Sheet1!B5   =Sheet1!B6   =Sheet1!D5
```

I can't figure out how to autofill down in Sheet2. I have hundreds of rows that need these formulas, and the last number in the sheet reference increments by 3 each time. There is probably an easy way to do it but FlashFill doesn't recognize the pattern.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer.

Put this all in Sheet2

Create a "helper" column in say, F, with the auto-fill number scheme 1,4,7,13, ... etc.

Then use the following formula to assemble the needed Sheet reference

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!" & "A" & F1)
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!" & "A" & F2)
...
```

Excel can recognize and flashfill that pattern.